# Calculate percentage in array javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
var data = 
    [
       {label:1, quater :'Q1', y:34},
       {label:2, quater:'Q1', y:20},
       {label:3, quater:'Q1', y:30},

       {label:1, quater:'Q2', y:77},
       {label:2, quater:'Q2', y:52},
       {label:3, quater:'Q2', y:3},

       {label:1, quater:'Q3', y:65},
       {label:2, quater:'Q3', y:12},
       {label:3, quater:'Q3', y:9},

       {label:1, quater:'Q4', y:77},
       {label:2, quater:'Q4', y:34},
       {label:3, quater:'Q4', y:5}
    ];
```

My goal is to add "percent" into each object. Each "percent" is the percentage of the value of y in current object devided by the sum of values of y in quater from Q1 to Q4. For example, the percent in first boject should be 34/(34+77+65+77)
The code below is what I tried. It works and calculats the data correctly. I am new to javascript, so I calculate the data step by step which makes the code look long.

I am wondering what is the smarter way to calculate the data to make the code shorter? Thanks!

```
var quater = ["Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"];
var sum = 0;
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i<quater.length; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j<data.length; j++){
    if (data[j]['quater'] == quater[i])
      sum = sum + data[j]['y'];        
  }
 //console.log(sum)    
 arr.push({
   'quater': quater[i],
   'sum': sum
 })
  sum = 0;
}
var arr1 = [];
var percent;
for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
  for(var j = 0; j<arr.length; j++){
    if(data[i]['quater'] == arr[j]['quater']){
      percent = data[i]['y']/arr[j]['sum'];
    }
  }
  //console.log(percent)
  arr1.push({
    'label': data[i]['label'],
    'y': data[i]['y'],
    'quater': data[i]['quater'],
    'percent': percent
  });
}

console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Can make a simple object that has `quater`'s as keys and has the sums as values.

Then iterate array again and calculate percentage

```
var totals={};

data.forEach(function(item){
  totals[item.quater] = (totals[item.quater] || 0 ) + item.y;
});

// totals now looks something like {Q3:18, Q1:16, Q4:66, Q1:12}

data.forEach(function(item){
   item.percent = 100 * item.y / totals[item.quater];
});
```

Assumes `label` is unimportant such as representing year. If not concatenate label , delimiter and `quater` into object keys

EDIT: i may have this backwards and need `label`'s as keys. Approaach is same

Comment: got 3 mins late, had made exactly same solution but with map instead of forEach haha

Comment: This is uncanny. My code was literally identical to yours, right down to the `totals` and `item` names. The only exception was the multiplication by 100 - there is some confusion about that in the question, so I left that out with a big TODO note about it. And a bit of difference in whitespace - I like spaces around the `=` and inside the parentheses, and between the `) {` too. Only mentioning those to show how minor the differences were - it was quite remarkable to see that we wrote the exact same code. I think that makes this the canonical solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` or `map` to this more efficiently. The first `map` is used to calculate the totals, the second `map` is used to calculate the percentages. See charlietfl answer, who beat me to the answer, for the `forEach` method which is pretty much identical.

```js
var data = 
    [
       {label:1, quater :'Q1', y:34},
       {label:2, quater:'Q1', y:20},
       {label:3, quater:'Q1', y:30},

       {label:1, quater:'Q2', y:77},
       {label:2, quater:'Q2', y:52},
       {label:3, quater:'Q2', y:3},

       {label:1, quater:'Q3', y:65},
       {label:2, quater:'Q3', y:12},
       {label:3, quater:'Q3', y:9},

       {label:1, quater:'Q4', y:77},
       {label:2, quater:'Q4', y:34},
       {label:3, quater:'Q4', y:5}
    ];

quartersum = {}

data.map(function(entry) {
  
  quartersum[entry.label] = (quartersum[entry.label]||0) + entry.y
  
})

data.map(function(entry) {
  
  entry.percent = entry.y / quartersum[entry.label] * 100;
  
  document.write(JSON.stringify(entry) + '<br>')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

I just followed the procedure of pushing the objects simultaneoulsy as I was calculating the percent values.

```
<script>
    var data =
            [
                {label:1, quarter :'Q1', y:34},
                {label:2, quarter:'Q1', y:20},
                {label:3, quarter:'Q1', y:30},

                {label:1, quarter:'Q2', y:77},
                {label:2, quarter:'Q2', y:52},
                {label:3, quarter:'Q2', y:3},

                {label:1, quarter:'Q3', y:65},
                {label:2, quarter:'Q3', y:12},
                {label:3, quarter:'Q3', y:9},

                {label:1, quarter:'Q4', y:77},
                {label:2, quarter:'Q4', y:34},
                {label:3, quarter:'Q4', y:5}
            ];



    var quater = ["Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"];
    var sum = 0;
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j<data.length; j++){
            if (data[j]['quarter'] == quater[i])
                sum = sum + data[j]['y'];
        }
        percent = data[i]['y']/sum;
        //console.log(percent)
        arr.push({
            'label': data[i]['label'],
            'y': data[i]['y'],
            'quater': data[i]['quarter'],
            'percent': percent
        });
        sum = 0;
    }


    console.log(arr);




</script>
```

Comment: While your algorithm works it has an o(n^2) complexity (you are iterating over the array for each entry), the previous answers given to you have a o(n) complexity, and can easily be adjusted to return your final array.